# Get data from JSON array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have this JSON array data:

```
[{"region":"Abersee","price":"1.298"},{"region":"Fuschl am See","price":"1.319"},{"region":"St. Gilgen","price":"1.317"},{"region":"Innerschwand","price":"1.321"},{"region":"Mondsee","price":"1.309"},{"region":"Abersee","price":"1.298"},{"region":"Mondsee","price":"1.309"},{"region":"Innerschwand","price":"1.321"},{"region":"Fuschl am See","price":"1.319"},{"region":"St. Gilgen","price":"1.317"},{"region":"Abersee","price":"1.298"},{"region":"Mondsee","price":"1.309"},{"region":"St. Gilgen","price":"1.317"},{"region":"Fuschl am See","price":"1.319"},{"region":"Innerschwand","price":"1.321"},{"region":"Abersee","price":"1.298"},{"region":"St. Gilgen","price":"1.317"},{"region":"Mondsee","price":"1.309"},{"region":"Fuschl am See","price":"1.319"},{"region":"Innerschwand","price":"1.321"},{"region":"Abersee","price":"1.298"},{"region":"Mondsee","price":"1.309"},{"region":"Fuschl am See","price":"1.319"},{"region":"St. Gilgen","price":"1.317"},{"region":"Innerschwand","price":"1.321"},{"region":"Abersee","price":"1.298"},{"region":"Fuschl am See","price":"1.319"},{"region":"Mondsee","price":"1.309"},{"region":"St. Gilgen","price":"1.317"},{"region":"Innerschwand","price":"1.321"}]
```

And I am not sure how to properly get the `region` and `price` data out. I tried this:

```
$array = json_encode($jsondata);
$json = json_decode($array, true);
echo $json['region'];
echo $json['price'];
```

But nothing appears. Any suggestions?

Comment: hint: `print_r($json);`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$array = json_encode($jsondata);
$json = json_decode($array, true);

foreach($json as $data){
    echo $data['region'] . "<br>";
    echo $data['price'] . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `json_encode` isn't needed, as you say - you already have that JSON data. Simply decode it, then loop over it. You are currently trying to access the first entry, but the conversion from JSON to PHP will add numeric indexes/array keys to the PHP array which don't exist in the JSON.

`foreach` over the array:

```
$jsondata = '[{"region":"Abersee","price":"1.298"},{"region":"Fuschl am See","price":"1.319"},{"region":"St. Gilgen","price":"1.317"},{"region":"Innerschwand","price":"1.321"},{"region":"Mondsee","price":"1.309"},{"region":"Abersee","price":"1.298"},{"region":"Mondsee","price":"1.309"},{"region":"Innerschwand","price":"1.321"},{"region":"Fuschl am See","price":"1.319"},{"region":"St. Gilgen","price":"1.317"},{"region":"Abersee","price":"1.298"},{"region":"Mondsee","price":"1.309"},{"region":"St. Gilgen","price":"1.317"},{"region":"Fuschl am See","price":"1.319"},{"region":"Innerschwand","price":"1.321"},{"region":"Abersee","price":"1.298"},{"region":"St. Gilgen","price":"1.317"},{"region":"Mondsee","price":"1.309"},{"region":"Fuschl am See","price":"1.319"},{"region":"Innerschwand","price":"1.321"},{"region":"Abersee","price":"1.298"},{"region":"Mondsee","price":"1.309"},{"region":"Fuschl am See","price":"1.319"},{"region":"St. Gilgen","price":"1.317"},{"region":"Innerschwand","price":"1.321"},{"region":"Abersee","price":"1.298"},{"region":"Fuschl am See","price":"1.319"},{"region":"Mondsee","price":"1.309"},{"region":"St. Gilgen","price":"1.317"},{"region":"Innerschwand","price":"1.321"}]';

$json = json_decode($jsondata, true);

foreach($json as $each)
    echo $each['region'] . ': ' . $each['price'] . PHP_EOL;
```

[Example](https://eval.in/151937)

**Edit**: a `print_r` of the decoded array (as mentioned by Marcin Orlowski) would show you its structure in PHP, similar to this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [region] => Abersee
            [price] => 1.298
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [region] => Fuschl am See
            [price] => 1.319
        )
```